# « Dormir à fond » : usage

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> Puis s'adressant toujours à sa femme : « marigeli, va réveiller Sylvelie, elle dort toujours à fond! Va lui dire. »

« À fond » semble signifier « profondément ».

Quoi qu'il en soit on ne trouve pas cette définition dans le TLFi, et de plus il me semble que de nos jours on ne dirait pas « dormir à fond » pour « dormir profondément » sauf en fait de plaisanterie, ce qui serait une insinuation que la personne se livre à l'activité de dormir avec assiduité.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fond))  b) **À fond.** Tout à fait, entièrement, jusqu'au bout.
> •  Examiner, étudier qqc. à fond; traiter un sujet à fond; travailler à fond; s'engager, se donner à fond dans une entreprise; connaître à fond la nature humaine; visser à fond.
> • À quoi servirait donc, ma chère petite sœur, d'avoir un frère en Russie si l'on ne savait pas à fond ce que c'est que le knout (J. de Maistre, Corresp.,1806-07, p. 270):
> • Comme il savait à peine conduire, il n'était pas mécontent que sa camionnette ne fût qu'un tacot, ce qui lui permettait d'appuyer à fond sur l'accélérateur sans dépasser le quarante. Queneau, Pierrot,1942, p. 160.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut confirmer que cet usage n'est plus normal ou que c'est une expression qui consiste de mots  rapportés qui n'a jamais réellement pris cours dans le passé ?

Comment: Je ne l'ai jamais entendu, mais ça peut être une maladresse de langage volontaire ou pas de la part de l'auteur/traducteur, ou un helvétisme.

Comment: Je suis très gênée par l'emploi de l'article défini dans « **le** dictionnaire », ceci sous-entend qu'il n'existerait qu'un seul dictionnaire. Nommer l'objet à cet endroit et pas juste dans la citation aurait été à mon avis  beaucoup  plus nuancé.

Comment: @none C'est corrigé !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En appui à la définition de @Circeus (« avec toute l'intensité possible ») citons le DHLF (ed. *Le Robert*). Extrait de l'entrée *fond* :

> ***À fond*** (1656) intensif, reprend métaphoriquement l'idée d'extrémité...

Cet emploi de *à fond* n'est pas inhabituel pour moi (et plaisant encore moins). Je l'ai déjà rencontré à l'oral comme à l'écrit, il peut bien sûr, comme pour tout fait de langue, y avoir des variations de fréquence selon les régions et/ou les habitudes culturelles des uns et des autres, mais en nier l'existence passée ou actuelle semble en contradiction avec la « réalité<sup>1</sup> ».

Les quelques exemples qui suivent sont le résultat d'une rapide recherche qui, bien que loin d'être exhaustive, suffira j'espère à montrer que cet usage n'est ni récent ni désuet.

> Même après 3 nuits à dormir à fond, les performances ne sont pas rattrapées
> ([22 conséquences très inquiétantes du manque de sommeil en 2023](https://sommeilprofond.fr/articles/manque-de-sommeil-consequences)) ;

> [vous m'avez donné la réponse : « Dormir à fond, se reposer à fond. »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/M%C3%A9decine_humaine_m%C3%A9decine_sociale/O-sJAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&dq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&printsec=frontcover) (*Médecine humaine, médecine sociale. Le docteur René Biot (1889-1966) et ses amis*, sld Régis Ladous, 1992) ;

> « [Cela ne m'empêche pas de dormir à fond et de suer à souhait](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Missions_en_Chine_au_Congo_aux_Philippin/EgMxAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&dq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&printsec=frontcover) » (Revue *Missions en Chine et au Congo*, 1906)

> « [Oui, dormir, dormir à fond, enfin...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=q8LPDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT169&lpg=PT169&dq=%22Oui,%20dormir,%20dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond,%20enfin...%20J%27avais%20les%20yeux%20ferm%C3%A9s,%20et%20je%20sentais%20encore%20ce%20petit%20sourire%20qui%20flottait%20malgr%C3%A9%20moi%20sur%20mes%20l%C3%A8vres.%20%22&source=bl&ots=rX4wrAehNP&sig=ACfU3U3SSyHbVvE2SZYF538jHjjJjWRinA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiau_jk38_-AhVhVKQEHRk4DHEQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Oui%2C%20dormir%2C%20dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%2C%20enfin...%20J%27avais%20les%20yeux%20ferm%C3%A9s%2C%20et%20je%20sentais%20encore%20ce%20petit%20sourire%20qui%20flottait%20malgr%C3%A9%20moi%20sur%20mes%20l%C3%A8vres.%20%22&f=false)  » (*Le secret de la dame en rouge*,Beatrice Bottet, 2019).

*Dormir à fond* est [une des traductions](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vocabulaire_et_grammaire_de_la_langue_ho/QtwZAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&dq=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%22&printsec=frontcover) de *Kuru sane* que donnait Maurice Leenhardt en 1935, expression du dialecte kanak de la vallée de Houaïlou<sup>2</sup>.

Si l'expression  « dormir à fond » me semble tout à fait naturelle, celle de « dormir à mort » à laquelle elle est juxtaposée dans *Apnée*<sup>1</sup> l'est moins et me semble plus du ressort de la création littéraire servant à illustrer le propos des auteurs, *à mort* donnant un cran de plus à l'intensité du sommeil.

> Dormir à fond, dormir à mort, faire la révolution en dormant, arrêter de se fatiguer à bouger dans tous les sens, arrêter de s'user à parler à tort et à travers, arrêter de penser, arrêter d'user les mots et le langage. [...] Dormir, ne plus penser, laisser nos cerveaux en friche [...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gOtfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22dormir+%C3%A0+fond,+dormir+%C3%A0+mort%27%22&source=bl&ots=f6paA8ilQU&sig=ACfU3U1_DYVGwC7dOrj_pvA2e6e9k5jPhg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5i8CBldH-AhXATqQEHSdvAXgQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22dormir%20%C3%A0%20fond%2C%20dormir%20%C3%A0%20mort%27%22&f=false).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Pour faire écho au « réellement » de la question.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> *Vocabulaire et grammaire de la langue houaïlou*. Institut d'ethnologie. Paris 1935.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> A. Boute, C. Schuiten, C. Thiry, J. Pruvot Simonneaux,Onlit–Editions. 2018.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que le problème tient à la formulation de la définition du TLFi, qui me semble un peu boiteuse. Si on l'examine en détail, elle n'est clairement applicable qu'à des [verbes téliques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9licit%C3%A9) (et difficile donc à appliquer pour certain verbes directement cités, comme "travailler").

Une définition plus générique serait "avec toute l'intensité possible". Et il est alors clair que *dormir à fond* est une utilisation légitime et plaisante (pas habituelle, mais tout à fait compréhensible) au sens de "dormir profondément".

Comment: Ce test de télicité semble délicat ; entre autres difficultés qu'il puisse y avoir, il peut dépendre du contexte, c'est à dire qu'un même verbe peut être considéré télique et atélique selon le contexte. Par exemple, dans « elle a examiné cela en une heure » le verbe est télique, et les cas de ce contexte ne sont pas rares ; dans « elle a examiné cela pendant une heure » il est atélique, les cas de contexte de cette dernière construction n'étant pas rares non plus. Si on cherche à savoir comment la loc. adv. « à fond » est affectée par ce phénomène rien de trop clair n'apparait. (1/3)

Comment: « elle a examiné cela à fond en une heure » et « elle a examiné cela à fond pendant une heure » sont toutes deux des construction exprimant un fait qui semble parfaitement réel. Dans la première, on tend à comprendre que l'examen est fait à fond, dans la seconde que le travail d'examen l'est. « Avec toute l'intensité possible » est certainement une addition possible à cette définition ; il semble que ça se voit dans « travailler à fond ». Elle ne convient plus lorsqu'il s'agit de « appuyer sur l'accélérateur ». (2/3)

Comment: C'est donc une question difficile que de savoir s'il exite ou non un empêchement logique pour utiliser « à fond » avec « dormir » selon cet aspect. Quoi qu'il en soit il me semble que la question ne se résout pas si simplement ; on ne dirait pas « la tête me fait mal à fond » et pourtant, c'est une « action » (du corps) dont on est conscient lorsqu'elle prend place et à laquelle on pourrait appliquer justement « avec tout l'intensité possible ». (3/3)

Comment: @Circeus il me semble que l'expression est plus familière que "plaisante", ce que semble confirmer l'origine sociale du personnage en question.

Comment: Au départ je ne voulais que faire un commentaire à ta réponse mais la tâche s'est avérée techniquement complexe. Je n’apporte rien de plus sur le fond.